# Mongoose save function doesn't exectue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
csvtojson.on('end_parsed', function(jsonObj) {
    async.eachSeries(jsonObj, 
        function(doc, cb_) {
            console.log("Updating " + doc["Name"] + ' ...');
            var r = new Segment({
                ...
            });

            r.save(function(err) {
                if(err) console.log(err);
                else console.log('Saved ' + doc["Name"]);
                cb_(null);
            });
        }, 
        function(error){
            fs.unlink(file, function(err) {
                if(err) console.log(err);
                else console.log('Deleted ' + file);
                var dir = './.tmp/' + file.split('/')[2];
                fs.rmdir(dir, function(err) {
                    if(err) console.log(err);
                    else console.log('Deleted ' + dir);

                    console.log('Update finished.');
                    console.log(error);
                });
            });
        });
});
```

The filestream is correct, reading is correct. But save function doesn't execute at all. The async function is always stuck at the 1st doc because callback function in the save callback doesn't execute.

Comment: Did you try console logging the error in line number 15 to confirm if there is no error?

Comment: what error shown for `console.log(err);`?

Comment: Are you sure that you're calling `mongoose.connect()` somewhere in your code?

Comment: The program is stuck at `r.save(function(err)` the only output is line 4. Yes, I connected with mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

```
r.save(function(err) 
            {
               if(err)
               {
                     console.log(err);
                     cb_(err);
                } 
                else {
                      console.log('Saved ' + doc["Name"]);
                      cb_(null);}
                 }
    );
```